# Transferring and replacing data between two sheets

Tags: excel, replace, transfer

I am putting together an excel sheet for a small hospital I volunteer at that would keep track of the incoming and outgoing patients.

I have a workbook and each sheet represents a different day in the ICU. New patients are automatically given a green label which then changes to red when their status is updated.

at the end of the day the patient is still in the ICU (No change is "Status»") then I want to be able to automatically transfer him to the subsequent page/day.

As requested, here is a simple pic that lays out what I would like to do:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/119219636@N06/

I hope this makes what i am trying to do a bit more clear.

Comment: Instead of pointing us at a large offline file, which is a PITA for mobile users, would you please revise your question to show the essence of what you're trying to do, and what you've tried? Note, please use pictures sparingly, and only if absolutely necessary to get the idea across.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I hope this clears things up a bit.